# Same menu on all pages without server languages?

Tags: html, css, frames

I need to do a simple information site on our intranet with multiple pages. I need to have the same menu on all pages. I know I can do it with php or other server language but I don't have it on the server. Another option is frames but it is a old and not recommend. Other solutions?

Comment: Just an external javascript and CSS file - or ajax it into a div

Comment: [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp) is the first result just googling your question

Comment: @LelioFaieta However w3scools is not a quality reference - and I can confirm that by looking at the horrendouse script they use to include a simple file

Comment: @mplungjan it was just to demonstrate that there are plenty of solutions out there googling. This is just the last of thousands of questions where no research effort have been done and asking us to write code for them. I agree this is not "the solution" but it is a suggestion to do a bit of research

Comment: [Minimal effort](https://www.google.nl/search?q=client+side+include+menu+on+all+pages+site:stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 0):

1. include a script that document.writes the menu

```js
document.write(`<style>/* CSSTerm.com Simple CSS menu */

br { clear:left }

.menu_simple {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #005555;
}

.menu_simple ul {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    float: left;
}

.menu_simple ul li {
    display: inline;
}

.menu_simple ul li a {
    float: left; text-decoration: none;
    color: white; 
    padding: 10.5px 11px;
    background-color:  #005555;
}
 
.menu_simple ul li a:visited {
    color: white;
}
 
.menu_simple ul li a:hover, .menu_simple ul li .current {
    color: white;
    background-color: #5FD367;
}</style><div class="menu_simple">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
</ul>
<br />
</div>`)
```

OR

2. ajax in the menu at load time - here using jQuery:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#menu").load("menu.html"); // #menu is a div with id=menu
});
```